# Problem with import variable in express, Error: Route.get() requires a callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-jwt

I try to import `requireSignin` from `controllers/auth.js` file to `routes/user.js` file and put it in the 
`router.get('/user/:id', requireSignin, read);` route.

I have the following error:

> Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object
>   Undefined]

**controllers/auth.js**

```
const expressJwt = require('express-jwt');

exports.requireSignin = expressJwt({
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET
});
```

**routes/user.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const {requireSignin} = require('../controllers/auth');
const {read} = require('../controllers/user');

router.get('/user/:id', requireSignin, read);

module.exports = router;
```

But if I don't import it, only I do it in another way, directly in one file `routes/user.js`. It works very well.

**routes/user.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const expressJwt = require('express-jwt');

const {read} = require('../controllers/user');

router.get('/user/:id', expressJwt({
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET
}), read);

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is quite clear to me. Please try to confirm it with a debugger (a severely underappreciated tool among the StackOverflow users), but it looks like the line `const {requireSignin} = require('../controllers/auth');` initializes the `requireSignin` with `undefined` instead of middleware function. There can be several reasons for this. Perhaps your IDE adds some parameter to node that prevents it from accepting the notation `exports.requireSignin` and you actually have to specify it as `module.exports.requireSignin`. If that's not it, assuming this is not the full version of your code and just simplified few lines to highlight the problem, make sure you don't have any typos between your import and export.

Comment: I had to use  module.exports.requireSignin